# Avoid an infinite loop but still ensure user validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

As part of the system I'm building a registered user needs to validate his email address, By clicking on a link in the following format:
`https://example.com/verification/${A key of 256 random characters}`
i use `crypto.randomBytes(128)` to generate the key.
After creating the key, i check that the key is not already in use, The problem is that i have to 
limit the number of tests, and i don't want to get to the point where 2 users get the same key.
How to deal with this situation? Limit the number of tests to a high number like 10,000 for example 
or is there a better way?

Comment: Are these random characters all being generated on the same server?  If so, you can just append a counter value that is incremented every time you generate one to the start or end of the random bytes.  The monotonically increasing counter ensures uniqueness.  Depending upon how many of these you need active at the same time, you can make your counter be as many bits as needed (32, 64, 128, etc...).  So, the counter just needs to cover the max of these you will create within an expiration time period (I'm assuming these expire after some period of time like 1 hour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.htm) in **NodeJs** uses the method [randomBytes(size[, callback])](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptorandombytessize-callback), where you can provide the value of the size in your case **265**, and implement the callback method that will take two arguments the **`err`** and the **`buf`** which represents a **Buffer** object with the generated values. This is an example of using the method :

```
const {
  randomBytes,
} = await import('node:crypto');

randomBytes(256, (err, buf) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  // Rest of the code
});
```

Now, if you want to make an algorithm that generates 100% unique keys each time for each user, let me tell you that this is impossible. Check the [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), for more information. However, you can follow one of the following 2 approaches:

1. If you are sure that the number of the user won't be more than a number **m**, and that your **algorithm** can generate **n** keys, knowing that `n>m` then you can do it (Pigeonhole principle).
2. You can follow an approach similar to a **database unique id**, where start with a number and **increment** it each time a new user is registered, and remove that key from your app after a certain period of time so you will not flood the server with useless data.

Comment: do I need to check if the new key is not in the buffer?
(in the callback)

Comment: The probability that the key is duplicated is really highly unlikely it's equal to `1 in 2^256`

Comment: I know, and it still bothers me, how can I guarantee the creation of a unique key every time?

Comment: There are multiple ways, one of the most used ones is to generate some suffix or prefix and add it to the key, for example, the current time

Comment: But if 2 users register at the exact same time, there is again the danger of 2 identical keys, I'm looking for a way where the key is 100% different

Comment: There is no way to generate a 100% unique key each time without making some checking first, again the suggested approach in the answer gives a possibility of 1 in 2^256 to duplicate the key, there are also other approaches like UUID, and since the size of the key is bigger the chance of duplicating it is almost 0%. You can add some other logic to the code to try to make the duplication more unlikely but there  is no ultimate guarantee

Comment: I edited the answer, and elaborate it